# AngularJS: Retain Login information when page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, authentication, cookiestore

I am trying to retain the user information when page refresh. I used `cookieStore` for this purpose. So my run module in the Angular App looks like this.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$cookieStore', '$state', function($rootScope, $cookieStore, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, $location){
        var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;

            if(typeof $rootScope.user == 'undefined'){
                $rootScope.user=$cookieStore.get("user");
                $rootScope.sessionid=$cookieStore.get("session");
            }
            if(requireLogin && typeof $rootScope.user === 'undefined'){
                event.preventDefault();
                 $state.go('login', null, {notify: false}).then(function(state) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', state, null);
                 });
            }
    });
```

Two main things I wanted to achieve from this is,

1. Have to get the `user` and `session`info from the browser's local storage, when page refresh.
2. If user is undefined, then it has to be redirected to the login page. It is for restricting the users to go to intermediate pages without login.

If user is `undefined`, and data is not available in the local storage, the first `if statement` gives error and the second `if statement` doesnot work.

So when the user tries to visit any page the first time without going to login page, it is not redirecting to the login page, because the code failed in first `if statement`, the second `if` not working.

How can I achieve both the functionalities together?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `authInterceptor` factory and push it in `interceptors`.

This method will always check if user is logged in or not on each page and will throw user on login page if he is not authenticated

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests. The **interceptors** leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this need for >both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.

Learn more about [**Interceptors**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
  return {
    // Add authorization token to headers
    request: function(config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
      }
      return config;
    },

    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
    responseError: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
        // remove any stale tokens
        $cookieStore.remove('token');
        return $q.reject(response);
      } else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
  };
})

.run(function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
  // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next) {
    Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
      if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
    });
  });
})

.factory('Auth', function Auth($location, $rootScope, $http, User, $cookieStore, $q) {
    var currentUser = {};
    if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
      currentUser = User.get();
    }

    return {
      /**
       * Gets all available info on authenticated user
       *
       * @return {Object} user
       */
      getCurrentUser: function() {
        return currentUser;
      },

      /**
       * Check if a user is logged in
       *
       * @return {Boolean}
       */
      isLoggedIn: function() {
        return currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role');
      },

      /**
       * Waits for currentUser to resolve before checking if user is logged in
       */
      isLoggedInAsync: function(cb) {
        if (currentUser.hasOwnProperty('$promise')) {
          currentUser.$promise.then(function() {
            cb(true);
          }).catch(function() {
            cb(false);
          });
        } else if (currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role')) {
          cb(true);
        } else {
          cb(false);
        }
      }
    };
  })

 .factory('User', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
          id: '@_id'
        }
      });
  });
```

With Above Mechanism, you can use `Auth` service to get `user` info in any `controller` or `directives` as:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Auth) {
  $scope.currentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;
});
```

in template file:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p> Hi {{currentUser().name}}!</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** You need to create a proper REST API in order to get correct `user` data

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and see.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using ngStorage. I use the sessionStorage object which will retain the data even on refresh. If you need further implentation example please let me know but the documentation is great.

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Thank you. Will look in to this.

Comment: I use it for most of my apps without issue. I recommend wrapping it in a factory so you can inject it. something like "storageService", Then call $scope.something = storageService.something. etc...